# Memory management in Objective-C and setting pointers to nil

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, garbage-collection

Will the pointer to an object go to `nil` when its count goes to 0 or when dealloc is called? Why or why not?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, it won't, because the deallocation does not have the power to change the pointer. It could only do this is you passed a *pointer* to the pointer.

If you want to ensure it's set to nil, you have to do it yourself.

Some consider this good practice, some consider it a waste of time since your code should be structured to not use pointers after deallocation (until reallocated).

I actually lean towards the latter camp but I can see why people want to protect themselves from accessing freed memory (programming defensively is rarely a bad idea).

Comment: I setup a macro to safely release a pointer and set it to `nil`.

Comment: +1 FYI, When using garbage collection, `__weak` pointers are "self-zeroing". Also, using a macro to do this can be error prone, as I mention in my answer below.

Comment: If you don't set a reference to nil when you are releasing, Leaks will not be able to tell you there is a memory leak - after all as far as Leaks is concerned you have a valid reference, even though you think the reference is no longer valid (over-retention).

Comment: Good point. The case where you still retain a valid pointer that you no longer use is considered abandoned memory, rather than a leak. Happily, you are very likely to see tools for detecting abandoned memory in future versions of Instruments... :-)

Answer (score 5):

Under the normal retain-release memory model, no. With garbage collection enabled, this happens if the pointer is declared as `__weak` (for Objective-C objects, the default is `__strong`). The garbage collector will zero out weak references for you when they are disposed of, which makes them ideal for pointing to delegates and semi-transient objects. See also [NSPointerArray](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPointerArray_Class/), [NSMapTable](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSMapTable_class/) and [NSHashTable](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/NSHashTable_class/) and their support for weak relationships as well. (NOTE: One must understand that a weak reference will not prevent an object from being garbage collected; it is zeroed when no strong references point to the same address. See [this document](http://developer.apple.com/leopard/overview/objectivec2.html) for a brief summary of this behavior.)

There are many other benefits to Objective-C garbage collection, and I heartily recommend using it if you can. (It's available on OS X 10.5+, but not on iPhone OS.) The performance improvements in Snow Leopard are most impressive, and it was already wicked fast to begin with.

That being said, *@darren* has a good point: it's usually good practice to nil your own variables when releasing their contents. If you're looking to avoid dangling pointers to over-released objects, your best bet is to adopt the habit of nilling the variable yourself. It won't incur runtime overhead, and it's readable. More importantly, setting variables to nil helps the garbage collection system work most effectively, since it indicates memory that can be safely reclaimed. The code will also then work in both modes perfectly.

However, I generally **don't** nil out values in `-dealloc` since the memory you're modifying is about to be reclaimed, and if some other part of the code may encounter an error due to using a released value, they ought not be using a deallocated object to begin with. (This often happens when one object hasn't properly retained another, and the latter is deallocated, leaving a [dangling pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer).) Possible exceptions to this might include staged tear-down where non-nil references might cause problems within dealloc itself, but this type of behavior generally doesn't (and shouldn't) occur when destroying an object.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if the pointer goes to nil or if it just points to invalid data, but its good coding convention to assign your variables to nil after you release them.

Comment: +1 This is great advice, particularly for instance and static variables, and doubly so under garbage collection, wherein you can accidentally accumulate strong references to unneeded memory that won't be reclaimed as desired. I think some people just want a magic bullet solution so they don't have to think about this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Think of this situation:

```
void *p = malloc (100);

while (someCondition)
{
    //  do something with p
}

free (p);

// p is not set to NULL for you, it still points to where it always did
```

Similarly, when an Objective-C object is deallocated, any pointers to that object are still pointing to where it was. This causes errors when another object is allocated into the same space (or even if nothing is allocated into the same space).